# How to calculate space and time complexity for this code

Tags: java, data-structures

```
public static int desc(int number) {

        // Time complexity = 2n+n2
        // space complexity = ?

        int i, j, temp;
        int array[] = new int[Integer.toString(number).length()];
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            array[i] = Integer.toString(number).charAt(i) - '0';

        for (i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++) {
                if (array[j] < array[j + 1]) {
                    temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = temp;

                }

            }
        }
        StringBuilder strNum = new StringBuilder();
        for (int k : array) {
            strNum.append(k);
        }

        int finalInt = Integer.parseInt(strNum.toString());
        System.out.println(finalInt);
        return finalInt;

    }
```

This is my code as *per* my understanding I am able to calculate time complexity please suggest if the time complexity is correct or not and also help me to calculate the space complexity of this program I am bit confuse on how to calculate of space complexity .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's optimize your code from:

```
int array[] = new int[Integer.toString(number).length()];
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    array[i] = Integer.toString(number).charAt(i) - '0';
```

to:

```
String to_number = Integer.toString(number);
int array[] = new int[to_number.length()];
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
     array[i] = to_number.charAt(i) - '0';
```

No need to call `Integer.toString(number)` multiple times.

Being `N` the number of digits in the parameter *number* (*i.e.,* `Integer.toString(number).length()`) the **time complexity** can be calculated as follows:

```
String to_number = Integer.toString(number);
```

has a time complexity of `N` and the same for:

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
     array[i] = to_number.charAt(i) - '0';
```

The follow up double loop:

```
 for (i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
     for (j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++) {
         if (array[j] < array[j + 1]) {
            temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j + 1];
            array[j + 1] = temp;
         }
     }
 }
```

is a [*well-know* for being](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4590/big-o-nested-for-loop-with-dependence) `N(N-1)/2`, which can be simplified to a time complexity of `O(N^2)`. The next loop

```
for (int k : array) {
     strNum.append(k);
}
```

has time complexity of `N`. Finally,

```
int finalInt = Integer.parseInt(strNum.toString());
```

is also `N`. So the time complexity is N + N + N^2 + N + N, which simplifies to `O(N^2)` time complexity, also known as *quadratic* time complexity.

Now let us look at the **space complexity**:

```
int array[] = new int[Integer.toString(number).length()];
```

in this case `N`, and

```
 for (int k : array) {
     strNum.append(k);
  }
```

also `N`, so the space complexity is `2N`, which simplifies to `O(N)`.

Comment: Wait, I got confused. The size of the array is not `number`, it’s the number of digits. So everything you did is 100% correct. Apologies, never mind me.

Comment: @KonradRudolph No problem, I appreciated that you took the time to explain the downvote.